# how to setup Flutter Firebase for desktop application

Tags: flutter, firebase

How do I set flutter to work with firebase functions like firestore, storage, and authentication?

```
Firebase.initializeApp()
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Are you asking setup firebase for flutter or adding firebase dependecies?

Comment: setting up firebase on flutter not depedencies.

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but if you are asking how to add firebase dependencies; you can get packages from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=firebase).

And in any one of them; click the installing  tab and use this code: flutter pub add xxx(depends on the package you use) for example for firebase auth:

```html
flutter pub add firebase_auth
```

Do not add dependencies directly to pubspec.yaml because it will make some mismatch with other packages. when you use flutter pub add xxx you don't get any problem with the harmony of dependencies.

---

Addition:
If you're asking how to use `Firebase.initializeApp()`  you need to call it where you will use Firebase. For example ;

```html
 Future<void> initializeDefault() async {
    FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    print('Initialized default app $app');
  }
```